# SQL request with a joining condition

Tags: mysql, sql, pdo

```
SELECT mairie.city, permission.permission
    FROM permission , user_mairie, mairie
    WHERE user_mairie.iduser = 1
    AND user_mairie.idmairie = mairie.idmairie
    CASE user_mairie.idrole
        WHEN 2 THEN 
            JOIN user_permission 
              ON user_permission.idpermission = permission.idpermission 
             AND user_permission.iduser = user_mairie.iduser
    END
    ORDER BY mairie.idmairie, permission.idpermission
```

I'm trying to get the permissions of a specific user if this user has a specific role.

A "mairie" is a "town hall" in french.

A user can have different roles in different "mairie"s.

If the user on user_mairie has idrole = 2, then we have to go to the table "user_permission" to get it's permissions.

If the user on user_mairie has idrole = 1 then he is admin and he has ALL permissions, but the permissions are not written in user_permission (because user_permission is used only for idrole = 2).

**What I want is for example :**

if the user_mairie.idrole = 1 :

```
SELECT * 
FROM permission
```

if the user_mairie.idrole = 2

```
SELECT * 
FROM permission, user_permission 
WHERE user_mairie.idrole = 2 
AND user_mairie.iduser = user_permission.iduser
AND user_permission.idpermission = permission.idpermission
```

I could do this using my programming language and making 2 requests, but I'd like to know if in pure SQL, this issue is solvable.

Some datas:

Table permission:

```
idpermission | permission
1            | permission_1
2            | permission_2
3            | permission_3
```

Table user_mairie :

```
iduser     | idmairie    | idrole
1          | 1           | 1
1          | 2           | 2
```

Table user_permission :

```
iduser     | idpermission  | idmairie
1          | 1             | 2
1          | 3             | 2
```

Table mairie :

```
idmarie     | city
1           | mairie_1
2           | mairie_2
```

The result I want (for a given iduser = 1) would be :

```
mairie_1 : permission_1, permission_2, permission_3
mairie_2 : permission_1, permission_3
```

Thanks for reading me.

Comment: These are substantially different queries, and there may not be a way to combine them into one single logical query.

Comment: `FROM permission , user_mairie, mairie` carthesians joins are deprecated since about 25 years. Consider using [`JOIN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html)

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed!

Comment: And never use `SELECT *`

Comment: Your queries are returning different *columns*.  That doesn't make sense.

Comment: It's generally better to use AND/OR instead of CASE expressions in the WHERE clause.

Comment: @Strawberry
- I wrote "SELECT *" to make the query easaier to read, but in my code, I have the needed fields.

Comment: @GordonLinoff no they have to return only the permissions the user have regarding of it's role on the mairie

Comment: @jarlh and cid : ok i'll try to use JOIN from now, but I have bad habbits

Comment: Combine your queries with UNION.

Comment: Tip: While it may make it easier to read, "SELECT *"  doesn't make a query easier to comprehend.

Comment: @Strawberry I've updated my post to add the fields I need and add some datas to make it simpler to understand my issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[SQL DEMO](https://rextester.com/KCUZ71667)**

First you start with all marie and all permissions

```
 SELECT um.idrole, m.city, p.permission
 FROM user_mairie um
 JOIN mairie m 
   ON um.idmairie = m.idmairie
 CROSS JOIN permission p 
 WHERE um.iduser = 1
```

Now you remove the permission you dont have

```
 WHERE um.iduser = 1
   AND (    um.idrole = 1 -- have all permission
         OR EXISTS (SELECT up.idpermission
                    FROM user_permission up
                    WHERE up.iduser = um.iduser 
                      AND up.idpermission = p.idpermission )
       )
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. Infact if the idrole = 1, I need ALL the permissions to get selected

Comment: Where you have the list of all permission?

Comment: in the table permission

Comment: I think is time you add some sample data and expected output.

Comment: What i want at the end is :

A list of 
- mairie.city : [all permission if idrole = 1, only user_permission if idrole = 2]
- other mairie.city ...

Comment: You want me to write some datas inside a comment?

Comment: I know you think is obvious for you. But please take the time to show us a table with sample data and expected output. You can edit your question. Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54748975/how-to-calculate-changes-in-oracle-sql)  See how gordon answer very quickly because the question desire result was more clear

Comment: Of course not ! I know it's not obvious, it's hard to explain for me cause i'm not english native. I'm trying to make it on the first post.

Comment: That is why is better use data tables. Those arent lenguaje dependent :)

Comment: We already have a good idea of what you need. But we already post 2 answer and wasn't what you want. Just add sample data and desire output so we can adapt our answer to that. Otherwise we get frustrated because we waste our time trying to guess what you want.

Comment: try now. is a weird condition but should work. Im still thinking if there is a smooth way.

Comment: I Include a Sql Demo

Comment: PERFECT YOU SOLVED MY ISSUE

Comment: Np. Told you is much easier when you know what you need :)

Comment: I change the `COUNT()` for `EXISTS`. I dont think can be done with `JOIN`

Comment: Ok I've updated the code and it still works perfectly, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you really want `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT . . .
FROM user_mairie LEFT um
     user_permission up
     ON um.iduser = up.iduser LEFT JOIN
     permission p
     ON up.idpermission = p.idpermission OR
        um.idrole = 1 ;
```

You may not want the condition on `idrole`.

This gets permissions only for id roles "2".

Notes:

- List all the columns you want in the `SELECT`.
- Learn to use proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax.  Never use commas in the `FROM` clause.
- Table aliases make the query easier to write and to read.
- Use `LEFT JOIN` so you can keep all the rows, even when there are no permissions.

Comment: as i understand it, there are no records in user_permission table for user with idrole = 2

Comment: @Jimmmy this is the opposite but you got the idea ! There are no record in user_permission for user with idrole = 1 !

Comment: Thanks for your query but I dont understand how I get the permission.permission without adding it inside the FROM (and the permission.permission is what I want)

Comment: @shqnks . . . Huh?  `permission` is in the `FROM` clause.  Just add it to the `SELECT`.

Comment: ok, I'll try it, but if the um.idrole = 1 I need all permissions, and if um.idrole = 2 I need to check out the user_permission table to see which permission the user have. I dont know if i'm understandable sorry

Comment: @shqnks . . . I modified the solution for that logic.